# How to deal with INF values when computting the average of values of a list in Python?

Tags: python

I've a list "L" which contains a huge amount of float elements.

My goal is to compute the average of "L".

I tried to use sum(L)/len(L), np.mean(L), ..., but it always gives 'inf' as a result, since sum(L) also return 'inf'.

I pretty sure that this is memmory issue and python as a limit to store certain values.

**I would like to know what are the best practices to deal with this issue?**

**Can 'inf' result be detected in runtime and through an if statment, compute average in a diferent way (like susbeting the main list into small ones and compute the averages bewtween them)?**

Answer (score 6):

You could try the following to compute the average of the array `arr`.

```
np.mean(arr[np.isfinite(arr)])
```

This will ignore both `NaN`s and `Inf`s.

For example:

```
arr = np.array([1, np.inf, 2, 3, np.nan, -np.inf])
np.mean(arr[np.isfinite(arr)]). # will produce 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using numpy try using [`np.isinf()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html):

```
>>> np.isinf([np.inf, -np.inf, 1.0, np.nan])
array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

> Returns a boolean array of the same shape as x, True where x ==
>   +/-inf, otherwise False.

↳ https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html

Comment: I have so many values in my list (20000 values) that i didn't notice that one of them was an INF, thx

Answer (score 0):

How many elements are you adding ? Do you have any values which might be 'inf'? you can find them with

```
np.any(np.isinf(...))
```

Comment: I have so many values in my list (20000 values) that i didn't notice that one of them was an INF, thx